# Android Workers, uniqueWork input data bug

Tags: android, worker, android-workmanager

I have created two Worker classes. One for uploading images and second for calling processing for uploaded images.

I'm initializing WorkManager and starts chained work.

```
public void uploadAndProcess() {
    workManager.beginUniqueWork("uploadAndProcessWork", ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, buildUploadRequest())
        .then(buildProcessingRequest())
        .enqueue();
}

private Data buildData() {
    return new Data.Builder()
        .putStringArray("vehicleIds", vehicleIds.toArray(new String[]{}))
        .putString("targetId", targetId)
        .putInt("position", position != null ? position : -1)
        .build();
}

private Constraints buildConstraints() {
    return new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build();
}

private OneTimeWorkRequest buildUploadRequest() {
    return new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class)
        .setInputMerger(OverwritingInputMerger.class)
        .setInputData(buildData())
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, OneTimeWorkRequest.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_DELAY_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .setConstraints(buildConstraints())
        .build();
}

private OneTimeWorkRequest buildProcessingRequest() {
    return new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ProcessWorker.class)
        .setInputMerger(OverwritingInputMerger.class)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, OneTimeWorkRequest.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_DELAY_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .setConstraints(buildConstraints())
        .build();
}
```

When I call `uploadAndProcess()` for first object, everything is OK. UploadWorker gets valid `vehicleIds` parameter. Images are uploaded, output is passed to second worker.

But, when `uploadAndProcess()` is called second time, for second object, valid `vehicleIds` is set inside `buildData()`, but received `vehicleIds` inside of a `UploadWorker` are from first object, first called UploadWorker.

I don't know is this some strange expected behavior or some bug in Workers.
**Is there any way to keep uniqueWork enqueue and have proper inputData parameters?** With regular enqueue work method, inputData in Workers are valid, as it should be.

Comment: setInputMerger(OverwritingInputMerger.class) doesn't helps. It is same w/o this call.